# Sign into a specific google account through third-party website

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, web

I am wondering if it is possible to let the user signs into a specific google account through a third-party website by clicking a button, assuming the credentials are supplied by the website itself? If it is, could anyone tell me how this could be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you will have to look into the page source of the 3rd party site and find the id of the username, password textbox and submit button. (If you provide a link I would check it  for you). Then use this code:

```
    //add a reference to Microsoft.mshtml in solution explorer
    using mshtml;

    private SHDocVw.WebBrowser_V1 Web_V1;

    Form1_Load()
    {
        Web_V1 = (SHDocVw.WebBrowser_V1)webBrowser1.ActiveXInstance;
    }

    webBrowser1_Document_Complete()
    {
    if (webBrowser1.ReadyState == WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
        {
            if (webBrowser1.Url.ToString() == "YourLoginSite.Com")
            {
                try
                {
                    HTMLDocument pass = new HTMLDocument();
                    pass = (HTMLDocument)Web_V1.Document;
                    HTMLInputElement passBox = (HTMLInputElement)pass.all.item("PassIDThatyoufoundinsource", 0);
                    passBox.value = "YourPassword";
                    HTMLDocument log = new HTMLDocument();
                    log = (HTMLDocument)Web_V1.Document;
                    HTMLInputElement logBox = (HTMLInputElement)log.all.item("loginidfrompagesource", 0);
                    logBox.value = "yourlogin";
                    HTMLInputElement submit = (HTMLInputElement)pass.all.item("SubmitButtonIDFromPageSource", 0);
                    submit.click();
                }
                catch { }
            }
        }
    }
```

Could you be a bit more specific and give a lot more details e.g. which site? Whose credentials?

Comment: thanks for the help, I was referring to the user's credentil. the user need to be able to log in to a google account by clicking a button on my page.

Comment: @cd9660 how will your program know the credentials? Will the user have input them before?

Comment: The credentials are build in the website, so all the user needs to do is just click the button and log in

Comment: @cd9660 I'm not sure what you mean with the credentials of user be saved in a website? Is it done with cookies? Btw. doesn't that count as an answer? Please upvote at least, I even gave you good to go code - thanks :)

Comment: sure, what i have in mind was letting a user directly log into the google account through the website, the username and password are stored in the backend and could be used directly. Upvote requires 15 reputation I am new to this site and only have 8.